# Find all circles in image

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to python & image processing. I am working on a hobby project in which I want to find ALL circles in image and then figure out which one have cross ('X') marked inside it. I have put some code together to find circles so far (below). It works on one image but fails to recognize all circles on another one. Please guide me how i can improve performance of find_circles algorithm.

Test Image:

[image: test image]

Result Image:

[image: result image]

```
import cv2
import cv
import numpy as np
import operator
from PIL import Image

def find_circles(img):
    im_gray = cv2.imread(img, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    img_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cv2.imwrite('img_bw.png',img_bw)
    rows, cols =img_bw.shape
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_bw,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,rows/32, param1=100,param2=40,minRadius=0,maxRadius=100)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    return circles

def draw_circles(img, circles):
    img = cv2.imread(img,0)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
        cv2.putText(cimg,str(i[0])+str(',')+str(i[1]), (i[0],i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, 255)
    return cimg 

def main():
    img = "query_circle9.png"
    circles = find_circles(img)
    img_circle = draw_circles(img,circles)
    cv2.imwrite('cricle.png',img_circle) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A link to the problematic image would be helpful.

Comment: Would you also post a link to the _original_ of the problematic image?

Comment: the unprocessed image would be nice, yes ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2

def draw_circles(img, circles):
    # img = cv2.imread(img,0)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
        cv2.putText(cimg,str(i[0])+str(',')+str(i[1]), (i[0],i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, 255)
    return cimg

def detect_circles(image_path):
    gray = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    gray_blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 13)  # Remove noise before laplacian
    gray_lap = cv2.Laplacian(gray_blur, cv2.CV_8UC1, ksize=5)
    dilate_lap = cv2.dilate(gray_lap, (3, 3))  # Fill in gaps from blurring. This helps to detect circles with broken edges.
    # Furture remove noise introduced by laplacian. This removes false pos in space between the two groups of circles.
    lap_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(dilate_lap, 5, 9, 9)
    # Fix the resolution to 16. This helps it find more circles. Also, set distance between circles to 55 by measuring dist in image.
    # Minimum radius and max radius are also set by examining the image.
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(lap_blur, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 16, 55, param2=450, minRadius=20, maxRadius=40)
    cimg = draw_circles(gray, circles)
    print("{} circles detected.".format(circles[0].shape[0]))
    # There are some false positives left in the regions containing the numbers.
    # They can be filtered out based on their y-coordinates if your images are aligned to a canonical axis.
    # I'll leave that to you.
    return cimg
```

The result:

```
cimg = detect_circles("circles.png")
```

[image: Detected circles]

There are some left-over false detection. If your images are aligned, then you can filter these false positives based on their y-coordinates. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: You are welcome. I think there are still a lot of challenges ahead for you. You'll realize that the algorithm is quite sensitive to the parameters for smoothing the image etc. Even though it appears to work ok for this image, it may not work for others. Depending on your background, I suggest considering a combination of machine learning to verify the circles, and using heuristics (alone or in an optimization framework) like the number of circles per line and col to further refine them. If you have any more problems like this, feel free to ping me or smth. Good luck :).

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'. How to correct it? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon The code was written in 2014 when OpenCV was still at 2.0+. It seems that since OpenCV 3.0 the `HOUGH_GRADIENT` constant have been moved to the `cv2` namespace so it is now cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT` (i.e., remove `cv` after `cv2`).